# How to Query If An Instance Exists Within A Many-To-Many Field On Django Queryset

Tags: django

Here are simplified model definitions

```py
class Resource(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    resources = models.ManyToManyField(Resource)
```

And I want to know for one type of `Resource`, the existence on each `Location`. So the json data I want is like

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "loaction_A",
        "resource": true
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2
        "name": "location_B",
        "resource": false
    },
    ...
]
```

I tried following view function but obviously got wrong results.

```py
def resource_view(request, res_id):
    res = get_object_or_404(Resource, pk=res_id)
    locations = Location.objects.values('id', 'name')\
        .annotate(resource=Q(resources=res))
    return JsonResponce({'locations': list(locations)})
```

I know I need something like below (in SQL)

```sql
select
    app_location.*,
    1 in (
        select resource_id
        from app_location_resources
        where location_id = app_location.id
    ) as resource
from app_location
```

How should I construct the queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more efficient way could be:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

locations = Location.objects.annotate(
    resource=Exists(
        Location.resources.through.objects.filter(
            location_id=OuterRef('pk'), resource_id=res_id
        )
    )
)
```

I would however advise to user a proper serializer like in the Django REST framework and perhaps use the Django REST framework: the serializer can then work bi-directional and for example makes it possible to render data in a comma-separated value (`.csv`) format.

Answer (score 1):

Get it work via `Exists` subquery

```py
def resource_view(request, res_id):
   res = get_object_or_404(Resource, pk=res_id)
   locations = Location.objects.values('id', 'name').annotate(
      resource=Exists(res.location_set.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')))
   )
   return JsonResponse({'locations': list(locations)})
```